# @ExceptionHandler for all controllers in spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, custom-error-pages

I have wrote following controller to handle all exception in my code:

```
@Controller
public class ErrorHandlerController {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public String redirectToErrorPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "error on server");
        return "errorPage";
    }
}
```

But looks like following exception handler will work only if exception throws inside `ErrorHandlerController`

I have a huge count of controllers. Please advice me how to write one ExceptionHandler for all controllers ?

P.S.

I understand that I can use inheritance but I don't sure that it is the best decision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the way you annotate your controller from *@Controller* to *@ControllerAdvice* that will make it a global exception handler

the docs say

> The default behavior (i.e. if used without any selector),  the 
>   @ControllerAdvice annotated class will  assist all known Controllers.

Also, you would have to change your method to something like

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ModelAndView redirectToErrorPage(Exception e) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("errorPage");
    mav.getModelMap().addAttribute("message", "error on server");
    return mav;
}
```

To understand why the *model* argument is not resolved in the method's annotated with @ExceptionHandler check out the *going deeper* part of the http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: In debug I see that I don't walk into controller method

Comment: yes, it will not resolve arguments in the global exception handler, I've made an edit

Comment: Yes, it works. But I don't understand the reason. Please explain.