# Spring Global Exception Handler - Not MVC

Tags: java, spring

Does regular Spring (Boot) have a way to do global exception handling, or at least catch any uncaught exceptions (such as `RuntimeException` that may happen randomly)?

I've googled around, but everything I've found talked about the `@ControllerAdvice` `@ExceptionHandler` for controllers. Nothing about just a general global exception handler.

I basically just want to make sure that if some exception happens that I'm not already catching, that I log it so I know about it.

Comment: Reading this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28678037/3959856 makes it sound like `@ControllerAdvice` is the way. Why not?

Comment: There is also `ErrorController` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorController.html which is onle level higher than ControllerAdvice or ExceptionHandler. But not sure if that is what you want

Comment: @JackFlamp I'm guessing OP is not using controllers, that's why this approach doesn't work

Comment: Why not using Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic That would kind of work, except threads get created and used in a couple places, and I'd be worried about not hooking this exception handler up to one of those places. My main goal is to make it impossible for an exception to not get logged. I general have good exception catching in most places, so I want something bullet-proof for the last step.

Comment: @JackFlamp As Lino mentioned, for this I'm not using controllers. My particular case is actually using `@Scheduled` to trigger tasks automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I think spring does not provide an out of the box solution for this.

A possibility to achieve this is using [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) with annotations (you may find an example here: [Where can I catch non rest controller exceptions in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164855/where-can-i-catch-non-rest-controller-exceptions-in-spring)). With this approach, you can define a global pointcut for all the methods annotated with a pre-defined annotation. The good part of this approach is to have all the error handling logic in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Add your own via AOP, something like this will work:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExceptionHandler {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "within(*.*)", throwing = "t")
    public void log(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Look at the [cheat sheet](https://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/20/aspectj-cheat-sheet/) to help with the pointcut.

Comment: Just like the OP, I have a Spring project that doesn't serve endpoints. I tried to add this to my `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` but it didn't work.

Comment: Although I actually got a `formal unbound in pointcut`, which means this may still work if I can fix this aspect thing.

Answer (score -2):

Best to extend Spring's `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class and customise it in a way you want, for example:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import javax.validation.ValidationException;

@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handle(ValidationException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(getError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handle(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        try {
            return super.handleException(ex, request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return handleExceptionInternal(ex, null, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, @Nullable Object body, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        if (HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR == status.series()) {
            log.error("Unexpected error.", ex);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(getError(status, ex), headers, status);
    }

    private ApiError getError(HttpStatus status, Exception ex) {
        return ApiError.builder()
            .status(status.value())
            .message(ex.getMessage())
            .build();
    }
}
```

This way you can override Spring's default error response body, declare your custom exceptions (e.g. `ValidationException`) as well as allow Spring to handle its default exceptions declared in `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`.

> Note although try-catch around `super.handleException(ex, request)` is not required in Spring 4.x, it is necessary in Spring 5.x due to a change of the underlying `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` implementation.

Comment: OP asked for a non MVC solution